# Matlab IIR Filter transfer function

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, matlab-deployment

I am using MATLAB to design a filter and obtain the transfer function coefficients `a` and `b` in order to then code the filter in C.

However I have noted that the function `sos2tf` is creating different values than expected. In fact when using `fvtool` to view the filter using the `b` and `a` coefficients the filter looks different than that of I plot it using the `sos` matrix or the actual filter `f`.

If you try the below code you can understand better what I am saying. Is this a function problem coming from MATLAB? Can I use substitutes to `sos2tf` which gives me the required filter coefficients? Or can I retrieve them directly without first using `sos`?

Note that I have already tried using `designfilt` and then using the `tf` function and the resulting coefficients came to be exactly equal to those obtained with the code below. Thanks for your help

```
H = fdesign.lowpass('Fp,Fst,Ap,Ast',60,75,1,60,10000);
f = design(H,'butter','MatchExactly','passband');  % Design an FIR BW filt
info(f)                   % View information about filter
fvtool(f);
[b,a] =  sos2tf(f.sosMatrix);
fvtool(b,a);
```

Comment: Could you please give me the filter specifications and the sampling frequency you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what the problem is, as it isn't working for me either, but I'm going to give you a workaround to get the filter coefficients. In Matlab Command Window type fdatool,a filter design app window will pop up, design your filter there by properly choosing the desired parameters. Once you're done, in that fdatool window go to File->Export->Export As-> Coefficients. From that very same tool you can select File-> generate matlab code-> Filter design function (or any of the 3 options). And that way you eliminate possible bugs there might be in the code you posted in your question. That's how I do it and it has always worked well

Comment: Even If I apply tf to extract the coefficients, after doing what you said I get a lot of noise up to the pass band f even though the filter is much better than the original. What bothers me is that if I apply fvtool to the sos values the filter comes out as designed, if I apply fvtool to the tf vectors th output filter comes different..its quite weird..

Comment: I have exactly the same problem: If you design the filter using the [b,a] syntax, you might encounter numerical problems. These problems are due to round-off errors and can occur for n as low as 4. 
And every filter above 4th order corrupts the signal.